# VSCode - Cannot Fold Comment Block

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, block, fold, folding

Ok - we've all all hit the wall with something pitifully stupid.  Today was my turn.

I couldn't fold (collapse) a comment block in VSCode.  Searched StackOverflow and others for a solution and came up dry.  The fix was so simple.  Answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

Indent the lines between the start and end block:

```
/*     
    indent these lines
*/
```